# Joomla, Scale iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe, joomla

For a friend who owns his own construction company iam building a website using Joomla, thus far i managed to do the most things he would like to see on his website. Now comes the time i need some help with it. On a other website people have written refrences about him, he would like to display them on his website. I said, ok no problem i just will use an iframe, hoping it was scaling itself, but it doesnt.

I found a couple of things how to correct this, but iam not able to find the correct .css file to scale it. The code iam using to scale the iframe

```
     /* iframe */
#wrap { width: 1130px; height: 100%; padding: 0; 
    overflow: hidden; position:relative;}
#frame { width: 100%; height: 100%; 
    border: 1px solid black; position:relative; }
#frame {
zoom: 0.75;
-moz-transform: scale(0.75);
-moransform: scale(0.75);
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;z-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-t
}
```

http://www.mb-ab.nl/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the template you're using is one you have personally developed then simply add it to the **template.css** file, however I'm assuming this is not the case.

You have 2 options, you can either:

1. As mentioned above, simply add your code to the template css file, however this is not recommended. If you ever update the template, then your changes will be overridden.
2. Use an plugin that will allow you to inject custom CSS into the `<head>` of your template. I would recommend [Add Custom CSS](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/head-code/25625).

Hope this helps

Comment: Alright, no i did not developed the template, i already tried to add the code to template.css but it didnt gave any results. So i will try option 2 in a few mins.

Comment: I think I know why it didn't work the first time. You are using `#frame` but does your iframe contain this ID?  If you're using this then you should have the following: `<iframe id="frame" .....`

Comment: <div style="border: 3px solid rgb(201, 0, 1); overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 736px;">
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.werkspot.nl/profiel/mbab/referenties" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -185px; height: 859px; margin-top: -533px; width: 926px;">
</iframe>
</div>

Comment: you will need to add `id="frame"` inside the `<iframe>` tag, else simply change `#frame {` to `iframe {`

Comment: Thnx for your time and info ! This worked, another thing learned today :)

Comment: You're more than welcome. Please accept the answer to mark it as solved by clicking the "tick" icon on the left